# In Gatling how to set the https port as 9443, which my test application listens?

Tags: gatling

My test application is not listening on default 443. How to set the port 9443 in Gatling? In documentation I can see a way to set httpsPort for Proxy server only.

ref - https://gatling.io/docs/3.1/http/http_request/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Its turns out be as simple as providing the port along with url

baseUrl = https://mytestserver.com:9443